# Arrange and Sub-sample 3d Points in Coordinate Grid With Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, linear-algebra, data-science

I have a list of 3d points such as

```py
np.array([
    [220, 114, 2000],
    [125.24, 214, 2519],
    ...
    [54.1, 254, 1249]
])
```

The points are in no meaningful order. I'd like to sort and reshape the array in a way that better represents a coordinate grid (such that I have a known width and height and can retrieve Z values by index). I would also like to down sample the points into say whole integers to handle collisions. Applying min,max, or mean during the down sampling.

I know I can down sample a 1d array using `np.mean` and `np.shape`

The approach I'm currently using finds the min and max in X,Y and then puts the Z values into a 2d array while doing the down sampling manually.

This iterates the giant array numerous times and I'm wondering if there is a way to do this with `np.meshgrid` or some other numpy functionality that I'm overlooking.

Thanks

Comment: Could you give an example of the output you are expecting? Do you want an array where `arr[220,114] = 2000`?

Comment: @tch yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

You can use the binning method from [Most efficient way to sort an array into bins specified by an index array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55226662/7207392)
To get an index array from `y,x` coordinates you can use `np.searchsorted` and `np.ravel_multi_index`

Here is a sample implementation, stb module is the code from the linked post.

```
import numpy as np
from stb import sort_to_bins_sparse as sort_to_bins

def grid1D(u, N):
    mn, mx = u.min(), u.max()
    return np.linspace(mn, mx, N, endpoint=False)

def gridify(yxz, N):
    try:
        Ny, Nx = N
    except TypeError:
        Ny = Nx = N
    y, x, z = yxz.T
    yg, xg = grid1D(y, Ny), grid1D(x, Nx)
    yidx, xidx = yg.searchsorted(y, 'right')-1, xg.searchsorted(x, 'right')-1
    yx = np.ravel_multi_index((yidx, xidx), (Ny, Nx))
    zs = sort_to_bins(yx, z)
    return np.concatenate([[0], np.bincount(yx).cumsum()]), zs, yg, xg

def bin(yxz, N, binning_method='min'):
    boundaries, binned, yg, xg = gridify(yxz, N)
    result = np.full((yg.size, xg.size), np.nan)
    if binning_method == 'min':
        result.reshape(-1)[:len(boundaries)-1] = np.minimum.reduceat(binned, boundaries[:-1])
    elif binning_method == 'max':
        result.reshape(-1)[:len(boundaries)-1] = np.maximum.reduceat(binned, boundaries[:-1])
    elif binning_method == 'mean':
        result.reshape(-1)[:len(boundaries)-1] = np.add.reduceat(binned, boundaries[:-1]) / np.diff(boundaries)
    else:
        raise ValueError
    result.reshape(-1)[np.where(boundaries[1:] == boundaries[:-1])] = np.nan
    return result

def test():
    yxz = np.random.uniform(0, 100, (100000, 3))
    N = 20
    boundaries, binned, yg, xg = gridify(yxz, N)
    binmin = bin(yxz, N)
    binmean = bin(yxz, N, 'mean')
    y, x, z = yxz.T
    for i in range(N-1):
        for j in range(N-1):
            msk = (y>=yg[i]) & (y<yg[i+1]) & (x>=xg[j]) & (x<xg[j+1])
            assert (z[msk].min() == binmin[i, j]) if msk.any() else np.isnan(binmin[i, j])
            assert np.isclose(z[msk].mean(), binmean[i, j]) if msk.any() else np.isnan(binmean[i, j])
```