# How to sort unique np array elements by occurence?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sorting

I would like to implement the following code:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]
sorted(a,key=a.count,reverse=True)
>>> [5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2]
```

For the case when `a` is a `np.array`

```
a = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5])
```

How to do it? np.array has `np.unique()` function that calculate occurence of each element, but I don't see how can I utilize it here.

Comment: In your example, both 3 and 4 occur three times.  Is it important that the 3s occurs before the 4s in the output?  I.e. are there special constraints that must be met in the case of ties?

Comment: Does your actual data contain just (relatively) small integers as in your example?

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exactly mimic `sorted`/`list` behavior @Divakar's soln can be used with a small modification:

```
al = [1,2,3,2,1,3,2]
aa = np.array(al)

sorted(al, key=al.count, reverse=True)
# [2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3]

u, ids, c = np.unique(aa, return_counts=True, return_inverse=True)
aa[(-c[ids]).argsort(kind="stable")]
# array([2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3])
```

If `aa` is large,

```
from scipy import sparse
sparse.csc_matrix((aa, (c.max()-c[ids]), np.arange(len(ids)+1))).tocsr().data
# array([2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3], dtype=int64)
```

may be slightly faster. Not much, though, because in both cases we first call the expensive `unique`, unless data are none too large integers in which case faster alternatives (to which @WarrenWeckesser appears to allude in the comments) are available including the sparse matrix trick we just used; see for example [Most efficient way to sort an array into bins specified by an index array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55226662/7207392).

```
aaa = np.tile(aa,10000)
timeit(lambda:aaa[(-c[ids]).argsort(kind="stable")], number=10)
# 0.040545254945755005
timeit(lambda:sparse.csc_matrix((aaa, (c.max()-c[ids]), np.arange(len(ids)+1))).tocsr().data, number=10)
# 0.0118721229955554
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with its optional arguments `return_counts` and `return_inverse` -

```
u, ids, c = np.unique(a, return_counts=True, return_inverse=True)
out = a[c[ids].argsort()[::-1]]
```

Sample run -

```
In [90]: a = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5])

In [91]: u, ids, c = np.unique(a, return_counts=True, return_inverse=1)

In [92]: a[c[ids].argsort()[::-1]]
Out[92]: array([5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `return_counts` which you can combine with `argsort` + `repeat`.  This will *not* guarantee the ordering of elements that appear the same number of times (notice the `4` before the `3`, same count, but not "stable").

---

```
u, c = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
i = np.argsort(c)[::-1]
np.repeat(u[i], c[i])
```

```
array([5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2])
```