# get minimum value across array of indices

Tags: python, numpy

I have an n-by-3 index array (think of triangles indexing points) and a list of float values associated with the triangles. I now want to get for each index ("point") the *minimum* value, i.e., check all rows which contain the index, say, 0, and get the minimum value from `vals` across the respective rows:

```py
import numpy

a = numpy.array([
    [0, 1, 2],
    [2, 3, 0],
    [1, 4, 2],
    [2, 5, 3],
])
vals = numpy.array([0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.6])

out = [
    numpy.min(vals[numpy.any(a == i, axis=1)])
    for i in range(6)
]
# out = numpy.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.6])
```

This solution is inefficient because it does a full array comparison for every `i`.

This problem is quite similar to numpy's ufuncs, but `numpy.min.at` doesn't exist.

Any hints?

Comment: Can you explain how you got to 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 in the output? any reproducible code?

Comment: @SANTOSHKUMARDESAI Did that.

Comment: Interesting optimization question. I think your solution is as good as it gets.

Comment: What if some ID is missing, say `a[0,1]` and `a[2,0]` are `0s`? So, we don't have `1` anywhere in `a`. Could that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `numpy.minimum.at` exists:

```py
import numpy

a = numpy.array([
    [0, 1, 2],
    [2, 3, 0],
    [1, 4, 2],
    [2, 5, 3],
])
vals = numpy.array([0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.6])


out = numpy.full(6, numpy.inf)
numpy.minimum.at(out, a.reshape(-1), numpy.repeat(vals, 3))
```

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1**

One approach based on array-assignment to setup a `2D` array filled up `NaNs`, using those `a` values as column indices (so assumes those to be integers), then mapping `vals` into it and looking for nan-skipped min values for the final output -

```
nr,nc = len(a),a.max()+1
m = np.full((nr,nc),np.nan)
m[np.arange(nr)[:,None],a] = vals[:,None]
out = np.nanmin(m,axis=0)
```

**Approach #2**

Another one again based on array-assignment, but uses `masking` and `np.minimum.reduceat` in favor of dealing with `NaNs` -

```
nr,nc = len(a),a.max()+1
m = np.zeros((nc,nr),dtype=bool)
m[a.T,np.arange(nr)] = 1
c = m.sum(1)
shift_idx = np.r_[0,c[:-1].cumsum()]
out = np.minimum.reduceat(np.broadcast_to(vals,m.shape)[m],shift_idx)
```

**Approach #3**

Another based on `argsort` (assuming you have all integers from `0` to `a.max()` in `a`) -

```
sidx = a.ravel().argsort()
c = np.bincount(a.ravel())
out = np.minimum.reduceat(vals[sidx//a.shape[1]],np.r_[0,c[:-1].cumsum()])
```

**Approach #4**

For memory efficiency and hence perf. and also to complete the *set* -

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def numba1(a, vals, out):
    m,n = a.shape
    for j in range(m):
        for i in range(n):
            e = a[j,i]
            if vals[j] < out[e]:
                out[e] = vals[j]
    return out

def func1(a, vals, outlen=None): # feed in output length as outlen if known
    if outlen is not None:
        N = outlen
    else:
        N = a.max()+1
    out = np.full(N,np.inf)
    return numba1(a, vals, out)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may switch to `pd.GroupBy` or `itertools.groupby` if your for loop goes way beyond `6`.

For instance,

```
r = n.ravel()
pd.Series(np.arange(len(r))//3).groupby(r).apply(lambda s: vals[s].min())
```

This solution would be faster for long loops, and probably slower for small loops (< 50)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one based on [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55226662/7207392):

If you have pythran, compile

file `<stb_pthr.py>`

```
import numpy as np

#pythran export sort_to_bins(int[:], int)

def sort_to_bins(idx, mx):
    if mx==-1:
        mx = idx.max() + 1
    cnts = np.zeros(mx + 2, int)
    for i in range(idx.size):
        cnts[idx[i]+2] += 1
    for i in range(2, cnts.size):
        cnts[i] += cnts[i-1]
    res = np.empty_like(idx)
    for i in range(idx.size):
        res[cnts[idx[i]+1]] = i
        cnts[idx[i]+1] += 1
    return res, cnts[:-1]
```

Otherwise the script will fall back to a sparse matrix based approach which is only slightly slower:

```
import numpy as np
try:
    from stb_pthr import sort_to_bins
    HAVE_PYTHRAN = True
except:
    HAVE_PYTHRAN = False

from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

def sort_to_bins_sparse(idx, mx):
    if mx==-1:
        mx = idx.max() + 1
    aux = csr_matrix((np.ones_like(idx),idx,np.arange(idx.size+1)),
                     (idx.size,mx)).tocsc()
    return aux.indices, aux.indptr

if not HAVE_PYTHRAN:
    sort_to_bins = sort_to_bins_sparse

def f_op():
    mx = a.max() + 1
    return np.fromiter((np.min(vals[np.any(a == i, axis=1)])
                        for i in range(mx)),vals.dtype,mx)

def f_pp():
    idx, bb = sort_to_bins(a.reshape(-1),-1)
    res = np.minimum.reduceat(vals[idx//3], bb[:-1])
    res[bb[:-1]==bb[1:]] = np.inf
    return res

def f_div_3():
    sidx = a.ravel().argsort()
    c = np.bincount(a.ravel())
    bb = np.r_[0,c.cumsum()]
    res = np.minimum.reduceat(vals[sidx//a.shape[1]],bb[:-1])
    res[bb[:-1]==bb[1:]] = np.inf
    return res

a = np.array([
    [0, 1, 2],
    [2, 3, 0],
    [1, 4, 2],
    [2, 5, 3],
])
vals = np.array([0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.6])

assert np.all(f_op()==f_pp())

from timeit import timeit

a = np.random.randint(0,1000,(10000,3))
vals = np.random.random(10000)
assert len(np.unique(a))==1000

assert np.all(f_op()==f_pp())
print("1000/1000 labels, 10000 rows")
print("op ", timeit(f_op, number=10)*100, 'ms')
print("pp ", timeit(f_pp, number=100)*10, 'ms')
print("div", timeit(f_div_3, number=100)*10, 'ms')

a = 1 + 2 * np.random.randint(0,5000,(1000000,3))
vals = np.random.random(1000000)
nl = len(np.unique(a))

assert np.all(f_div_3()==f_pp())
print(f"{nl}/{a.max()+1} labels, 1000000 rows")
print("pp ", timeit(f_pp, number=10)*100, 'ms')
print("div", timeit(f_div_3, number=10)*100, 'ms')

a = 1 + 2 * np.random.randint(0,100000,(1000000,3))
vals = np.random.random(1000000)
nl = len(np.unique(a))

assert np.all(f_div_3()==f_pp())
print(f"{nl}/{a.max()+1} labels, 1000000 rows")
print("pp ", timeit(f_pp, number=10)*100, 'ms')
print("div", timeit(f_div_3, number=10)*100, 'ms')
```

Sample run (timings include @Divakar approach 3 for reference):

```
1000/1000 labels, 10000 rows
op  145.1122640981339 ms
pp  0.7944229000713676 ms
div 2.2905819199513644 ms
5000/10000 labels, 1000000 rows
pp  113.86540920939296 ms
div 417.2476712032221 ms
100000/200000 labels, 1000000 rows
pp  158.23634970001876 ms
div 486.13436080049723 ms
```

UPDATE: @Divakar's latest (approach 4) is hard to beat, being essentially a C implementation. Nothing wrong with that except that jitting is not an option but a requirement here (the unjitted code is no fun to run). If one accepts that, the same can, of course, be done with pythran:

`pythran -O3 labeled_min.py`

file `<labeled_min.py>`

```
import numpy as np

#pythran export labeled_min(int[:,:], float[:])

def labeled_min(A, vals):
    mn = np.empty(A.max()+1)
    mn[:] = np.inf
    M,N = A.shape
    for i in range(M):
        v = vals[i]
        for j in range(N):
            c = A[i,j]
            if v < mn[c]:
                mn[c] = v
    return mn
```

Both give another massive speedup:

```
from labeled_min import labeled_min

func1() # do not measure jitting time    
print("nmb ", timeit(func1, number=100)*10, 'ms')
print("pthr", timeit(lambda:labeled_min(a,vals), number=100)*10, 'ms')
```

Sample run:

```
nmb  8.41792532010004 ms
pthr 8.104007659712806 ms
```

`pythran` comes out a few percent faster but this is only because I moved `vals` lookup out of the inner loop; without that they are all but equal.

For comparison, the previously best with and without non python helpers on the same problem:

```
pp           114.04887529788539 ms
pp (py only) 147.0821460010484 ms
```