# Ordering points in 3D according to grid

Tags: numpy, sorting, histogram

I have an array of points in 3D. I want to do something close to what [np.histogramdd](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogramdd.html) does, but instead of the count of number of points in each bin, I want to return the actual coordinates of the point(s) therein: zeros if there are none, exact xyz if there is just one, and an xyz average if there are two or more, in the order specified by the bins. Should I just modify the source code for histogramdd accordingly, or perhaps there's a quicker/cleaner way?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recipe:

1. Use `np.digitize` to obtain bin indices for each coordinate of each point
2. Use `np.ravel_multi_index` to transform to flat bin indices
3. Finally,

   1. either use [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55226663/7207392) to group points by bin
   2. or use `np.bincount` to get the bin counts and, using the optional second argument, to sum coordinates per bin

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Will post what I got.